# mysql Levenshtein wildcards?

Tags: mysql, sql, user-defined-functions

I have a search on my website that was searching Like this

```
SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE `ARTIST` LIKE '%Live%' 
GROUP BY `ARTIST` ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN `ARTIST` LIKE 'LIVE' THEN 0 
WHEN `ARTIST` LIKE 'LIVE%' THEN 1
WHEN `ARTIST` LIKE '%LIVE%' THEN 2
ELSE 3, `ARTIST`
```

This works extremely well for me until spelling mistakes start happening. If there is a spelling mistake, I either get the wrong results or (which is more likely) no results.

I found the levenshtein UDF's on

http://samjlevy.com/2011/03/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/

After playing around with it for awhile I relised wildcards '%' don't work.

Can wild cards be used and if not, is there a function that has both properties of LIKE and levenshtein joined where it will replace letters and find a word in a long string of words

Comment: Levenshtein is to tell you how similar 2 words are so a wildcard is meaningless. However as it is not fast and you would need to compare every artist using this fairly slow check you would find the responses fairly slow. You can try soundex and / or metaphone functions to get a simple representation of the words and then compare those (indexed) against the soundex / metaphone of your search string

Comment: Thanks @Kickstart but I would have prefered to have been able to search like I stated. I'm not the biggest fan of soundex as my db has artists that are Zulu and such so soundex kinda falls down here. I'll probably land up building a algo in php to sort this mess out

Comment: I have been writing a search system for a work site. My basic method was to index all the words (so in your case explode out the artist name into a list of words), with a link list for the items for that word. Then when someone searches I take their search string and explode that out into individual words. For each word I find all the indexed words which start with the same letter and have about the same number of characters. For those words I then use levenshtein (in php) to find the best matches, then find the items that contain those words. This does cope fairly well with spelling mistakes.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitly look into this. It does seem to be the best way to cope with typing errors. Would you reccomend then saving each word into the DB as my own sort of custom "dictionary"?

Comment: That is the way I have done it. Along with an index of common typos (so maybe Jonh for John), and also one of common alternative words (so maybe Jon for John). I then possibly do the search several times (so if someone searched for "John Wayne" it might do a 2nd search for "Jon Wayne"). Also I do not bother to index certain words. Results in about 75k words indexed, and about 800k links between items and words.

Comment: When you say some words arn't indexed, I take you mean simple single and double character words?

Comment: For mine, yes. Things like A, THE, AND or other very common words. If you are searching for names then you would probably have a far smaller list of these.